# java is not taking system locale

Tags: system, locale

Java is not taking system locale that i specified in the control panel-change display language - administrative - change system locale.

When i am running the below code:

```
public static void main(String s[])
{
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().toString());
}
```

I alway get output as below

```
en_ZA
```

I specified portuguese as system locale but i get output as en_ZA instead of pt_PT.

Comment: How do you run this code? In a shell? IDE?

Comment: What's your user locale?

Comment: i run this  code IDE and my user locale is Portuguese

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 7, Oracle has changed the way `Locale.getDefault()` works.

You must change the display language of the os. merely changing the region format is no longer sufficient.

see : [this oracle bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7073906)

Comment: keep in mind that at least older versions of java used to get the locale values when the JVM is initialised, and changing it afterwards does not seem to update the value.

Comment: i have changed the display language also but it is not working.